# phoneGap : save entire div in window.localStorage.setItem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am a complete to phoneGap. I have dynamically created `div` and i wish to store these dynamically created `div` `window.localStorage.setItem`. How do i do this by javascript?

On page load I need to `getItem` i.e. get all divs and display them.

Code: to create div dynamically:

```
var addDiv = document.createElement("div");
addDiv.id = "div_multi";
document.getElementById("add-questions").appendChild(addDiv);

var btnRemove = document.createElement("input");
btnRemove.type = "button";
btnRemove.value = "Delete";
btnRemove.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteSelectedQuestion(this)");
addDiv.appendChild(btnRemove);

var btnSave = document.createElement("input");
btnSave.type = "button";
btnSave.value = "Save";
btnSave.setAttribute("onclick", "saveSelectedQuestion(this)");
addDiv.appendChild(btnSave);

var btnEdit = document.createElement("input");
btnEdit.type = "button";
btnEdit.value = "Edit";
btnEdit.setAttribute("onclick", "editSelectedQuestion(this)");
addDiv.appendChild(btnEdit);

var lblQuestion = document.createElement("div");
lblQuestion.innerText = "Question. ";
addDiv.appendChild(lblQuestion);

var questionText = document.createElement("input");
questionText.type = "text";
questionText.id = "multi_question" + i;
addDiv.appendChild(questionText);

var lblAnswer = document.createElement("div");
lblAnswer.innerText = "Answer. ";
addDiv.appendChild(lblAnswer);
```

How do i store this?

Comment: just get the innerHTML of your div and then call window.localStorage.setItem. Is it something more complicated you're trying to do?

Comment: actually i have many divs- for eg. user created a div for 4 checkboxes, then another div for 5 radio buttons and so on. now when i click on save, i need to save all of these controls in localStorage.setItem. Then on page load, I need to get all these controls and display them. I hope you got my point. How do i do this?

Comment: should i store the div values in array?

Comment: You could save them as string in localStorage(for cache), then on page load, you try to get them from localStorage, if you don't find, you retrieve from server or generate it by yourself. I think one presentation will help you [Lessons from Building LinkedIn Mobile](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/linkedin-html5-nodejs?utm_campaign=infoq_content&utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=feed&utm_term=global)

Comment: I think tou should save them individually and then have an index object that you would also save in localstorage using json representation.

Comment: can you please provide an example or sample code for the same? as you said i am using innerHTML property, and storing the string in localStorage. Now how do i retrieve the element based on this string?